# Convert byte array from PLC to JSON or Java Object

Tags: java, json, deserialization, json-deserialization

Is there a way to get a json or Java object out of an byte stream?

If the structure in the plc looks like that

```
Data
  - id       int
  - pos      array[0..3] of int
  - time     dint

id=5
pos[0]=1
pos[1]=2
pos[2]=3
pos[3]=4
time = 5
```

I would get a bytearray of `[0,5,0,1,0,2,0,3,0,4,0,0,0,5]`

Now I want a Json out of this like

```
{
  id:5,
  pos:[1,2,3,4],
  time:5
}
```

The Deserialization Process needs to know the `Datatypes` and the `Array lengths`. Is there any framework which supports things like that?

Answer (score 0):

JSON is just text, so you would convert the JSON object to a string, transfer that string, and then convert it back into whatever JSON library data structure you are using.